# Commit signing ok on local workstation, but fails at same workstation over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, gnupg

I'm working on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64 machine (fully patched). The machine has a GNOME3 desktop. Sometimes I sit at the workstation, and other times I SSH into the workstation.

When sitting at the workstation Git commit signing works. I use `git commit -S ... -m ...`, and things work as expected. I get a UI prompt for my GnuPG password and the work flows as usual.

When I work remotely on the same workstation over SSH I have to forgo commit signing because:

```
$ git commit -S log.h -m "Remove unneeded header"
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I'm using a "standard" configuration for SSH, Git and GnuPG. I am not aware of any special configurations for this setup. However, the repo is located on my local LAN (and not GitHub, GitLab, etc):

```
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@callmaster:/var/callboot-src
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

There is no specialized GnuPG conf file in `$HOME/.gnupg`:

```
$ ls -A ~/.gnupg/
3F537D88ADBC1677-private-key.asc  pubring.kbx
private-keys-v1.d                 trustdb.gpg
```

Search is not finding the issue. I'm getting a lot about Git signing failures, but not results for this particular situation.

What configuration option am I missing so signing works locally and over SSH?

---

Here is `pinentry` on the machine:

```
$ ls -Al /usr/bin/pinentry-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63992 Feb  5  2018 /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72184 Feb  5  2018 /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Sep  2 19:14 /usr/bin/pinentry-x11 -> /etc/alternatives/pinentry-x11
```

And then:

```
$ ls -Al /etc/alternatives/pinentry-*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Sep  2 19:14 /etc/alternatives/pinentry-x11 -> /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Sep  2 19:14 /etc/alternatives/pinentry-x11.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/pinentry-gnome3.1.gz
```

Comment: Which `/usr/bin/pinentry-*` programs do you have installed, and what is `/usr/bin/pinentry` symlinked to?

Comment: @grawity - The information was added to the question. I don't recall doing anything special for `pinentry`. It was probably installed as part of gnupg or git-core or ssh. Or maybe it is part of the base-os. I don't recall the order I installed the packages (if order matters).

Comment: Now open in Ubuntu Issue Tracker: [pinentry does not work for both desktop login and SSH login](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pinentry/+bug/1852696)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your shell startup files (.bashrc or .zshrc) set the $GPG_TTY environment variable:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

There are several layers of indirection in the way GnuPG shows password prompts. It doesn't show them directly, and it doesn't even launch the "pinentry" UI directly – instead it passes a few relevant environment variables to a *gpg-agent* daemon (which is shared across all of your sessions), and then gpg-agent tries to start "pinentry" on the correct TTY or the right X11 display.

For some yet unexplained reason, when *gpg* sends the session information to *gpg-agent*, it doesn't bother looking up the real TTY by itself (or even passing it as file descriptor); it *always* expects the $GPG_TTY environment variable to be present and contain the information.

---

As an alternative, you can kind of avoid this by enabling the "loopback pinentry" option, where gpg-agent's passphrase requests travel back to *gpg* instead of starting a pinentry UI.

To do so, add the option `pinentry-mode loopback` to ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf.

(In older (outdated) GnuPG versions, you might also need the option `allow-loopback-pinentry` in ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf, and after adding it you'll need to update with `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`. Latest GnuPG already allows loopback mode by default.)

Comment: Thanks @grawity. No joy using `GPG_TTY`. I added the variable to `.bashrc`, logged out over SSH, logged in over SSH, and verified with an echo: `/dev/pts/1`. Signing experienced the same error.